# DD sda1 (or whatever) to a file. Then at some point mount that file as ISO or some other means?

Tags: linux, disk-image

Death to Windows. I am done with it.

I would like to preserve the Windows partition in case I will need it later.  I was wondering if I can use `dd` to copy the partition to some file so that if I need to I can restore the partition as-is.  That if, in the course of things I need some files from that partition (file), can I mount the file like an iso file.

1. `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/my/preserved/windows.iso`
2. mount `windows.iso`

Is that doable?  Is there another method/suggestion?

Comment: Yes. `mount -o loop /path/to/image/file /place/to/mount`

Comment: Yes it works however you remove the partition table, not all filesystems are recognized the same way on unpartitioned (super floppy,like) devices. Alternatively you could skip a few sectors and add a new partition table to the loopback mount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work as long as you have the tools to read the `ntfs` partition that resides on Windows.